# Bash: Symlink Following

Tags: bash, filesystems, symlink, overwrite, data-analysis

I've got a file tree containing a bunch of data I've generated. I've decided that at several stages of the data generation, I'd like to try some different configuration options in the programs that get used.

My solution was duplicating the data tree, and symlinking to all of the original data (multiplied by the number of new tests that I'm running). Then I'd let the programs clobber away the symlinks as needed. The result would be symlinks to the original tree for data that didn't get affected by my new configurations, and real data for anything new.

The problem is that the `-clobber` option on most of the programs I use follow symlinks, so it in fact clobbered over my original data. Is there anything I could try (maybe something like bash environment settings?) that might make all of these programs clobber the actual symlink, rather than the data it points at?

Answer (score 0):

This is probably not possible - the option likely works by simply opening the file in 'truncate' mode - to replace a symlink it would actually have to delete the file [the  symlink] beforehand with a separate function. You could try setting the permissions (`chmod -w`) on the original data file to not allow writing, but that might simply stop it from working

Answer (score 0):

Do the programs check whether the new output is the same as the old before writing? If not, then it doesn't seem like the symlinks will offer any advantage, since the datastore will always uniquified in the course of running the analysis.

Are you able to change the way that the programs write their output? The following sequence will avoid following the symlink:

1. write the new output to `out.tmp`
2. if the old output `out` and `out.tmp` are identical, delete `out.tmp`
3. otherwise, move `out.tmp` on top of  `out`

How big is the data? Is it big enough that it's worth the effort to optimize the storage requirement? You can always save the full output, and run some analysis (in the simplest case, `diff`) after the fact to see if the data is the same.

If it is many GBs of data, you may want to look in to a filesystem that will optimize the duplicate data for you (the feature is known as "de-duplication"). Or, you can use [LVM's snapshot support](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/LVM-HOWTO/snapshotintro.html), which allows cheap copy-on-write snapshots of a filesystem.

As a poor-man's de-duplicating file system, you can do something like this in bash:

```
for file in $output_files; do
    md5=`md5sum $file | awk '{print $1}'`
    if [ ! -f "db/$md5" ]; then
        mv $file db/$md5
    fi
    ln -sf db/$md5 $file
done
```

Comment: Yeah, the main tree is a few hundred GB, so I can't really duplicate. I don't have control over the programs at all. My temporary solution is running everything through a wrapper that deletes output files before running, kind of like you suggested. I really need a nice way to trick the programs into thinking that the links are regular files.

Comment: @ajwood You only want to trick the programs some of the time, though... something needs to have the intelligence not to write a new copy of the data if it hasn't changed. I added a quick and dirty way of de-duplicating the data to my answer, applicable if there are many entirely unchanged output files.

Comment: The setup I've got is such that I can control where the execution starts -- I don't need to worry about duplication of the stuff near the start of the run. What I *do* need, is for the programs that end up running, that they clobber the simlinks rather than clobbering the target of the simlinks. I'm afraid that there's no real good answer to my problem though.